# Uniqueness of smooth structure on embedded submanifolds - circular logic in Lee?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I've been reading Chapter 5 of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, where the author presents several characterisations of embedded submanifolds, leading up to a proof of the fact that there is only one smooth structure that you can put on an embedded submanifold that makes it an embedded submanifold.

Unfortunately, the argument in Lee's book appears to me to be circular.

But seeing that Lee's book has been used by so many people for such a long time, I'd be surprised if there really is a problem with the argument in the book. It's more likely that I have misinterpreted the argument in the book, or missed some key insight.

Could somebody kindly take a look at my interpretation of the argument and tell me if I have misunderstood it?

---

### My interpretation of the argument

**Step 0:** the definition of embedded submanifolds. We say that a subset $S \subset M$ is an embedded submanifold if there exists some smooth structure on $S$ compatible with the subspace topology on $S$ such that the inclusion map $\iota : S \to M$ is a smooth embedding.

**Step 1:** the local slice condition. We show that if $S \subset M$ satisfies the local slice condition, then $S$ has a natural smooth structure that makes it an embedded submanifold.

[A chart $(U, \phi)$ on $M$ is a *local slice chart* for $S$ if $\phi(S \cap U) = \{ (x^1, \dots , x^k, x^{k+1}, \dots, x^n ) \in \phi(U) : x^{k+1} = \dots = x^{n} = 0 \}$. $S$ satisfies the local slice condition if every point on $S$ is contained inside a chart on $M$  that is a local slice chart for $S$. ]

Having covered $S$ with local slice charts, it's easy to come up with a smooth atlas for $S$. For example, the local slice chart $(U, \phi)$ in the paragraph above gives rise to a chart $(U \cap S, \pi \circ \phi)$ on $S$, where $\pi$ is the projection onto the coordinates $x^1, \dots, x^k$. It is easy to see that two compatible charts $(U_1, \phi_1)$ and $(U_2, \phi_2)$ on $M$ that are local slice charts for $S$ give rise to two compatible charts $(U_1 \cap S, \pi_1 \circ \phi_1)$ and $(U_2 \cap S, \pi \circ \phi_2)$ on $S$.

**Step 2:** existence of slice charts for embedded submanifolds. This is sort of a converse of Step 1. We show that if $S \subset M$ is an embedded submanifold, then every point in $S$ is contained in a chart $(U, \phi)$ for $M$ that is a local slice chart for $S$. This follows from a simple argument based on the rank theorem.

**Step 3:** restriction the codomain of a smooth map. We show that if $S \subset M$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$ and $F: N \to M$ is a smooth map show image is contained in $S$, then the restriction $F: N \to S$ is also smooth. (Apologies for the abuse of notation, where $F$ denotes two different maps with two different codomains.)

To do this, we first observe that the restriction $F : N \to S$ is continuous, since $S$ has the subspace topology. To prove smoothness, let $p \in N$ be arbitrary and let $q = F(p) \in S$. We take a smooth chart $(U, \phi)$ for $M$ that is a local slice chart for $S$ centred at $q$, which is possible as a consequence of Step 2. This (supposedly) gives us a chart $(U \cap S, \pi \circ \phi)$ for $S$ centred at $q$, as per Step 1. Since $F$ is continuous, the set $F^{-1} (U \cap S)$ is an open neighbourhood of $p$ in $N$. Taking any chart $(V, \psi)$ for $N$ such that $p \in V \subset F^{-1} (U \cap S) $, the fact that $M$ is smooth means that the coordinate representation $\phi \circ F \circ \psi^{-1}$ for $F : N \to M$ with respect to the charts $(V, \psi)$ and $(U, \phi)$ is smooth. But then the coordinate representation $(\pi \circ \phi) \circ F \circ \psi^{-1}$ for $F : N \to S$ with respect to the charts $(V, \psi)$ and $(U \cap S, \pi \circ \phi)$ is also smooth. This shows that $F$ is a smooth map from $N$ to $S$.

**Step 4:** uniqueness of smooth structure on embedded submanifolds. Suppose $S \subset M$ is an embedded submanifold. Suppose $\tilde{S}$ is $S$ endowed with some smooth structure *different* from the original smooth structure on $S$ such that the inclusion map $\tilde\iota : \tilde S \to M$ a smooth embedding. By Step 3, the smooth map $\tilde\iota : \tilde S \to M$ restricts to a smooth map $\tilde\iota : \tilde S \to S$. This map $\tilde\iota : \tilde S \to S$ is an immersion (since the composition of $\tilde\iota : \tilde S \to S$ with the inclusion map $\iota : S \to M$ is an immersion). Since $\tilde\iota : \tilde S \to S$ is also bijective, it follows from the rank theorem that it is in fact a diffeomorphism. This shows that the smooth structures on $S$ and $\tilde{S}$ are in fact the same.

---

### Why the argument appears to be circular

In Step 3, $S$ comes with some smooth structure such that the inclusion $S \to M$ is a smooth embedding. The thing we're trying to prove in Step 3 is that the restriction $F : N \to S$ is smooth with respect to *this* smooth structure on $S$. (Step 3 *must* be interpreted this way in order for the conclusion of Step 3 to be applicable to Step 4.)

We claim that $(U \cap S, \pi \circ \phi)$ is a chart for $S$, but what we're really claiming is that $(U \cap S, \pi \circ \phi)$ is compatible with the *original* smooth structure on $S$.

This supposedly follows from Step 2, where we show that charts of the form $(U \cap S, \pi \circ \phi)$ (with the $(U, \phi)$'s being charts for $M$ that are local slice charts for $S$) give us *a* smooth structure on $S$.

The problem is that the smooth structure on $S$ induced by these local slice charts might not be the *same* smooth structure as the *original* smooth structure on $S$. In other words, given a chart $(U, \phi)$ for $M$ that is a local slice chart for $S$, $(U \cap S, \pi \circ \phi)$ might not be compatible with the original smooth structure on $S$.

To say that $(U \cap S, \pi \circ \phi)$ is compatible with the original smooth structure on $S$, we need to appeal to the conclusion of Step 4, where we showed that any two smooth structures on $S$ for which the inclusion $S \to M$ is a smooth embedding must be the same.

But Step 4 was derived from Step 3! Hence the argument is circular.

---

### How I went about fixing the argument

After thinking for a while, I restructured the argument in my own way. Let me sketch this out.

**Step 1:** the local slice condition. As in Lee's book. So suppose we are given a subset $S \subset M$ and a collection of charts $\{ (U, \phi) \}$ for $M$ that cover $S$, where each $(U, \phi)$ is compatible with the smooth structure on $M$ and where each $(U, \phi)$ is a local slice chart for $S$. Then we can construct a smooth structure on $S$ that makes $S$ an embedded submanifold of $M$.

**Step 2:** existence of slice charts for embedded submanifolds. As in Lee's book. So suppose we are given a subset $S \subset M$ with a smooth structure that makes $S$ an embedded submanifold of $M$. Then we are able to construct a collection of charts $\{ (U, \phi) \}$ for $M$ that cover $S$, where each $(U, \phi)$ is compatible with the smooth structure on $M$ and where each $(U, \phi)$ is a local slice chart for $S$.

**Step 2a:** Show that the construction in Step 1 is the inverse of the construction in Step 2. In other words, given a subset $S \subset M$, we can use the construction in Step 2 to get an collection of charts for $M$ consisting of local slice charts for $S$, and then we can apply the construction in Step 1 on these local slice charts that we've just constructed to get a "new" atlas for $S$. One can then show that this "new" atlas on $S$ is not really new - it is in fact compatible with the original smooth structure on $S$.

**Step 2b:** Suppose $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal C'$ are two different collections of charts for $M$ compatible with the smooth structure on $M$, both covering $S$ and both consisting entirely of local slice charts for $S$. Then the smooth structures induced on $S$ by applying the construction in Step 1 to $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal C'$ are the same.

**Step 2c:** uniqueness of smooth structures on embedded submanifolds. Step 2a and Step 2b together imply that if $S \subset M$ is an embedded submanifold, then any two smooth structures on $S$ making $S$ an embedded submanifold of $M$ must in fact be the same.

**Step 3:** restriction of the codomain of a smooth map. As in Lee's book, except that this time, we have *already* proved the uniqueness of smooth structures on embedded submanifolds, so we no longer run into problems with circular logic.

---

Did I misinterpret Lee's argument? Did I miss some key insight? Do I really need to restructure the argument in the book to get the logic straight? I'd be grateful for your input.

Comment: Lee maintains a list of errata: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/errata.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi29eKelZz-AhWQX8AKHd57BYUQFnoECCIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1KZlSeHXSd18E1C4iT_WXo   It's pretty up to date, and there are chunky corrections in there. But this isn't one of them...